# Anführungszeichen als Ironie-Indikator bei geteiltem Verb

Tags: punctuation, quotes

Um hervorzuheben, dass ein Wort euphemistisch gebraucht wird oder, dass es eigentlich nicht ganz seinen normalerweise zugedachten Inhalt widerspiegelt, kann man Anführungszeichen nutzen:

> Hans "arbeitet" schwer im Home-Office. (Hans schaut eigentlich eine Serie auf Netflix)

> Hans hat gestern seine Wohnung "aufgeräumt". (Hans hat einen Teller in den Geschirrspüler geräumt).

Wie verhält es sich denn, wenn das Verb geteilt ist?

> Hans räumt morgen seine Wohnung auf.

> a) Hans "räumt" morgen "auf"
> b) Hans "räumt" morgen auf
> c) Hans räumt morgen "auf"

Comment: Die Anführungszeichen sind Ironie-Marker. In deinem Beispiel mit "umziehen" ist nicht klar, was hier ironisch sein soll. Wenn sich die Ironie auf "um" beziehen soll (vielleicht weil Hans in die Wohnung unter seiner gegenwärtigen Wohnung zieht, und daher nicht wirklich "um"-zieht?!), dann würde man nur "um" in Anführungszeichen setzen, bei dem anderen Worteil analog. Vielleicht kannst du ein Beispiel nennen, bei dem klarer ist, was die Ironie ausdrücken soll.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach: Ohne dem OP Worte "in den Mund" legen zu wollen - das Beispiel lässt sich vermutlich direkt aus der Frage ableiten: "Hand räumt morgen seine Wohnung auf.", gemäß dem entsprechenden Beispiel oben.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper jup, kann man so nehmen.

Comment: Ich hätte die Anführungszeichen um "morgen" gesetzt. Gibt dieses wunderbare Lied von den Beginnern, in dem es heißt: Morgen is bei uns was anderes als der nächste Tag
Morgen is eher mit dem Moment zu vergleichen
Wenn die FDP es schafft 40 Prozent zu erreichen

Comment: Problematisch ist die Verwendung von Hochkommas bei einzelnen Worten, wenn das Wort eigentlich eine ganz normale Bedeutung hat, so aber umgebaut wird: *Die "Migranten" füllen alle Wartezimmer, dass keiner mehr durch kommt* - hier wird der Mensch dahinter mit dem geläufigen Terminus Migrant als eben kein Migrant und damit auch kein Mensch gebrandmarkt. Ist jetzt ein Substantiv als Beispiel, für mich zeigt es eine der Grenzen von Ironie/Hochkomma bei einzelnen Worten im Schriftlichen.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm: "als eben kein Migrant und damit auch kein Mensch gebrandmarkt" - wieso jemand, der (nach Ansicht des Hochkommasetzenden) kein Migrant ist, damit automatisch auch kein Mensch sein soll, erschließt sich mir nicht.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm: Insgesamt verstehe ich den Kommentar nicht so ganz. Die in Hochkommata gesetzten Wörter haben doch *immer* "eine ganz normale Bedeutung" (s.o. "arbeiten", "aufräumen"), gegenüber der die Hochkommata eine Abweichung (für gewöhnlich ins Negative) andeuten sollen, oder etwa nicht?

Comment: @O.R.Mapper: ja, in "normalen, neutralen Texten" funktioniert "" wie ich üblicherweise annehme. Es ist nach meiner Wahrnehmung Sitte u.a. bei den Rechtsextremen, mit den eigentlich objektiven Begriffen mit "" ihre Geheimsprache zu verwenden - und deren Bedeutung ist signifikant negativer als ein "jaja, 'aufräumen' = nur eine andere Form von Unordnung". D.h., es gibt mehr als nur Ironie oder Betonung durch "" - und ich muss achtgeben, dass meine "" so verstanden werden wie ich es meine. Der einzelne Satz mit "sogenannte Migranten" mag neutral klingen, der weitere Kontext ergibt Ironie j/n.

Comment: Bemerkung am Rande: Im Deutschen werden Kommas immer unten gesetzt. Hochkommas gibt es nicht. Was es gibt, das ist das Apostrophzeichen und dessen Einsatz als Ersatz für Anführungsstriche ist falsch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ignoriere die pedantischen Angriffe gegen die Vorstellung von Ironie in der Sprache. Wenn man ein Verb durch Anführungszeichen hervorhebt, egal zu welchem Zweck, und das Verb geteilt wird, dann stehen die Anführungszeichen natürlich um beide Teile, also ist a) richtig.

(Am Rande: Davon unabhängig muß man natürlich darauf achten, daß *eine* der Verwendungen von "" ist, ein wörtliches Zitat zu kennzeichnen, und wörtliche Zitate dürfen nicht verändert werden. Wenn also das Originalzitat das Verb ungetrennt verwendete, z.B. im Nebensatz, dann darf man es nicht so umformulieren, daß das Verb getrennt wird.)

Answer (score 1):

Weder, noch und schon gar nicht.

> Hans räumt morgen seine Wohnung auf.

Wenn es Ironie sein soll, und man will diese unbedingt mit Anführungszeichen ausdrücken, dann kommt der ganze Satzteil in solche:

> Hans "räumt morgen seine Wohnung auf".

Es ist für den Leser natürlich nicht ersichtlich, worauf sich die Ironie bezieht. Behauptet Hans selbst, dass sein Tellerrücken aufräumen sei? Wem gegenüber? Dass es nur ein Teller war kann der Leser natürlich nicht erraten. Verrät man es, dann braucht man die Anführungszeichen nicht.

Comment: D.h., es ist ausgeschlossen, die Ironie nur auf einen Teil zu beziehen? Also nur auf morgen, nur auf das aufräumen, nur auf seine, nur auf Wohnung, nur auf Hans - das geht alles nicht so wie im Mündlichen?

Comment: @ShegitBrahm, meines Erachtens können nur Aussagen ironisch sein, und Aussagen brauchen in der Regel ein Prädikat, vielleicht sogar ein Subjekt. Ein einzelnes Wort, zum Beispiel *Wohnung* bildet aber noch keine Aussage und kann daher, isoliert betrachtet, auch nicht ironisch sein. Die Frage *Ist Wohnung ironisch gemeint?* ergibt keinen Sinn, die Frage *Ist es ironisch gemeint, dass Hans morgen seine Wohnung aufräumt?* hingegen schon.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: danke für die Ausführung. Ich finde halt schon, dass ich *im Mündlichen* eher die Frage nach "ist <Satzteil> ironisch gemeint?" höre und verwende als dass ich den ganzen Satz hinterfrage. Vielleicht ein bequemes *ist das ironisch gemeint?* - nicht jedoch alles wiederhole. Eben weil ich wegen der Betonung fast heraus gehört habe, worin die Ironie steckt.

Comment: @ShegitBrahm: Betont man nur einen Verbteil stellt der Hörer sich die Frage: "Er **räumt** nicht auf, sondern was? Isst er die Wohnung auf? Sperrt er sie auf?" bzw. "Er räumt nicht **auf**, sondern um, ab, ein?". Betont man beide klingt es nach gar nichts. Man muss also den ganzen Satzteil betonen oder wie betonst Du ironisch, wenn Hans in seiner bekannten Art die Wohnung aufräumt? Die Anführungsstriche versuchen ja die Betonung sichtbar zu machen.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich Natürlich kann "Wohnung" ironisch gemeint sein. Die Ironie drückt dann aus, dass man meint, Hans wohne eigentlich nicht in einer Wohnung, sondern vielleicht in einem "Loch" oder einem "Palast".

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach, Sie verwechseln **Ironie** mit **Euphemismus**. Ein Euphemismus kann eine einzelnes Wort sein, wie etwa *Wohnung* als Beschönigung für *Loch* oder *aufräumen* für *mal gründlich ausmisten*. Ironie hingegen bezieht sich auf eine Behauptung oder Aussage. *Er räumt die Wohnung auf* ist eine Behauptung, kann also potenziell ironisch gemeint sein, *Wohnung* ist hingegen keine Behauptung und kann folglich gar nicht die Eigenschaft haben, ironisch gemeint zu sein.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: Ich habe den Verdacht, wir sprechen hier die ganze Zeit vom falschen Konzept. Die Anführungszeichen deuten wohl insgesamt eher Euphemismen an (auch in den Beispielen des OP, "aufräumen" und "arbeiten").

Comment: @O.R.Mapper, das vermute ich auch. Diese Verschmelzung von eigentlich verschiedenen Konzepten beobachte ich auch in anderen Gruppen und Foren. Und am Ende weiß keiner mehr, was gemeint ist, weil alles Eins ist.